# Parent data text field not recognized in Kendo TreeView when using data attribute initialization

Tags: telerik, treeview, kendo-ui

I'm trying to using Kendo TreeView with attribute data initialization, following [the official documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/data-attribute-initialization) . As far as I understand, the next two portions of code should be equivalents:

1.- data attribute initialization style:

```
  <div id="treeview-right" 
             data-role="treeview" 
             data-source="inline"
             data-text-field="['categoryName', 'subCategoryName']">
  </div>
```

2.- JQuery style:

```
<script>
            $("#treeview-right").kendoTreeView({
            dataSource: inline,
            dataTextField: ["categoryName", "subCategoryName"]
            });
</script>
```

The way number 2 works as expected, but the number 1 renders the tree but without the parent node's text(showing 'undefined' text, like it doesn't recognize the 'categoryName' parameter from data-text-field value. By the way , when I set data-text-field to `data-text-field="['categoryName']` it shows the parent node text, but not the child node's text, as expected. I'm using [the example](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/local-data.html) from the official tutorial (JQuery style initialization), if someone wants to see the whole code. Is it correct my supposition?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug. It will be fixed for the next release. Here is [the link](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/treeview/parent-data-text-field-not-recognized-in-kendo-treeview-when-using-data-attribute-initialization.aspx) to the oficial kendo forum awnser.